# How to save html array with Django forms?

Tags: django-forms

I have some html form with fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name="input[]">
<input type="text" name="input[]">
<input type="text" name="input[]">
<input type="text" name="input[]">
```

How i can save this form with django forms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use [`QueryDict.getlist`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

```
inputs = request.POST.getlist('input[]')
```

it's not mandatory to put `[]` in the name

`<input type="text" name="input">...`

Comment: This not the correct answer! He has mentioned Django Forms!!! But you are using simple request!

Comment: Not a nice solution, but you can call getlist in from clean method.